# How to properly integrate bootstrap sass files to react components and use it

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-5

I am cleaning up the folder structuring and file imports of my mini-project and I used react-bootstrap as my UI framework. Currently, all styling is working fine but I am thinking that all my CSS may become bloated. What I have is I am importing bootstrap SCSS files in the App.scss and also in the component level I am importing it again just to use the Bootstrap Grid and do my updates there.

Inside my App.scss I have this

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid';
...
html, body {
  font-family: var(--font-main, sans-serif);
}
* {
  font-family: var(--font-main, sans-serif);
}
// rest of codes
```

Then in the component level, I have this also

```
// File path: resources/js/components/ProductsCategory/ProductsCategory.scss

@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid';

@import '../../../scss/custom_mixins';
.featured-category {
... some codes here
}

// Access this bootstrap mixin
@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    .featured-category {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

This approach is working but if I remove the Bootstrap import inside the component sass, the bootstrap function will throw an error that it is looking for missing dependencies.

Like this one - https://prnt.sc/advNovvQZYo3

By the way I am using Bootstrap 5 (react-bootstrap)